# GraphQL Query for track order status in Shopify iOS

Tags: ios, shopify, ios11, swift4, shopify-app

I am new in GraphQL and Shopify also. My requirement is track order status using shopify iOS SDK and i am unable to find any solution to track order status.

I am able to get user's order list using this query

```
{
  customer(customerAccessToken: token) {
    orders(first: 20) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          orderNumber
          totalPrice
          currencyCode
          customerLocale
          customerUrl
          email
          phone
          processedAt
          subtotalPrice
          totalRefunded
          totalShippingPrice
          totalTax
          shippingAddress {
            address1
            address2
            city
            company
            country
            countryCode
            firstName
            formatted
            formattedArea
            lastName
            latitude
            longitude
            name
            phone
            province
            provinceCode
            zip
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have been doing lots of R & D but not got any solution to track order status.

Can any one help me??

Answer (score 0):

```
customer(customerAccessToken: accessToken) { $0
            .orders(first: orders, after: cursor, reverse: true) {$0
                .pageInfo { $0
                    .hasNextPage()
                }
                .edges {$0
                    .cursor()
                    .node {$0
                        .id()
                        .orderNumber()
                        .name()
                        .processedAt()
                        .fulfillmentStatus()
                        .originalTotalPrice{$0
                            .amount()
                            .currencyCode()
                        }
                        .subtotalPriceV2 {$0
                            .amount()
                            .currencyCode()
                        }
                        .totalShippingPriceV2{$0
                            .amount()
                            .currencyCode()
                        }
                        .totalPriceV2 {$0
                            .amount()
                            .currencyCode()
                        }
                        .shippingDiscountAllocations {$0
                            .allocatedAmount{$0
                                .amount()
                                .currencyCode()
                                
                            }
                        }
                        .discountApplications(first:discounts){$0
                            .edges {$0
                                .node{$0
                                    .allocationMethod()
                                    .onDiscountCodeApplication{$0
                                        .allocationMethod()
                                        .applicable()
                                        .code()
                                    }
                                    .value{$0
                                        .onPricingPercentageValue{$0
                                            .percentage()
                                        }
                                        .onMoneyV2{$0
                                            .amount()
                                        }
                                        
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                        .lineItems(first: lineItems){$0
                            .edges{$0
                                .node{$0
                                    .quantity()
                                    .title()
                                    .variant{$0
                                        .priceV2{$0
                                            .amount()
                                            .currencyCode()
                                        }
                                        .image{$0
                                        .url()
                                        }
                                        .unitPrice{$0
                                            .amount()
                                            .currencyCode()
                                        }
                                        .selectedOptions{$0
                                            .name()
                                            .value()
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```